# OpenVPN asks to import config file, how or from where can I import it?

Tags: openvpn

I've installed OpenVPN 2.4.8 and, to connect, it's asking to import a config file. 
What is a config file, and how, or from where, can I import one?

- I remember the last time I used OpenVPN I didn't need any config files: I clicked connect, entered username and password, and it worked.

Comment: The reason OpenVPN didn't request the importation of a config file and certs when last used is that the config file and certs were already within either your user's OpenVPN config directory or the system-wide config directory.  Since these can be customized, use the OpenVPN Start Menu shortcut `OpenVPN\Shortcuts\config` to open the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenVPN a config file (.ovpn) is used to ease creating the required account and configuration to access a specific VPN server. It usually contains account information, protocol configurations and certificates required.

This config file is provided by the operator or administrator of this specific VPN server.

If you have all required information's, you still can configure the VPN connection yourself.

Comment: _"If you have all required information's, you still can configure the VPN connection yourself"_.: OpenVPN requires a config file & certs and these cannot be configured via the OpenVPN GUI.  While it is possible to configure those options via CLI, it's highly inefficient and would still require cert and key files, including the `tls-crypt` PSK.